# Mocking ES6 React Components

Tags: reactjs, mocking, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am attempting to mock a dependency to one of my ES6 React components, but I think I've really hit a dead end at this point.  I've been researching options on google for probably two hours now, but none of the solutions seem to work and I think I've exhausted all options.  The last solution I attempted, "babel-preset-rewire," seemed the most promising, but it's throwing an error even when I follow the docs to a T.  Here is my attempt at using this babel plugin, but I am also open to other mocking options.

.babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["rewire"],
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

Spec

```
import { SignUp } from './signUp';

SignUp.__Rewire__('TopBarContainer', class TopBarMock {
  render() {
    return (<div></div>);
  }
});
```

This isn't even extending React.Component, but the goal was just to get something basic working. I can't even seem to get the **Rewire** function to export with the module... When I try running the above code, the following error message is thrown:

> TypeError: _get__(...).**Rewire** is not a function